# Unable to install dowloaded rpm package

Tags: installation, dockerfile, rpm, yum

I downloaded the rpm file from https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm  to local.I want to install that dowloaded file in centos environment.
However when i give "yum -y install ius-release-1.0-15.ius.centos7.noarch.rpm" in my dockerfile,I am getting an error "error: open of ius-release-1.0-15.ius.centos7.noarch.rpm failed: No such file or directory".
Aim is to install the local rpm package which is resting in the directory where dockerfile is present.
Please help me !

Is it that i am not giving the right path of that rpm file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command needed would be `yum -y localinstall <filename>` but you will need to modify your `Dockerfile` to `ADD` the file to the docker image first.

Comment: Thankyou !Yes the problem was ,i am trying to install it without moving to the container. Thats why i got the error "Could not open the dir" as the file itself is not present.After moving it to app/(i.e. container) , yum -y install <package name> itself worked for me.